# What is the optimal algorithm for this problem?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Consider a set A = a1, a2, . . . , an−1, an of n items where each ai is a positive integer and a value Z as input for the following problem:
Is there a subset A0 = {ai1, ai2, . . . , aik} ⊆ A such that
Z = ✷ai1✷ ai2✷ . . . ✷ aik where ✷ is + or −?.

For example, if the given input is {3, 5, 4} and Z = 2 we can have 2 = −3+5. while we do not have any combination for Z = 10. For Z = 6 we have the combination 6 = −3+5+4.

Write a recursive function IsSummable(Z, A) that determines whether it is possible to find

a subset A0 ⊆ A such that the value Z can be realized by a combination of the elements
A0 using only two operations + or −.

Comment: This looks very similar to [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and is probably also NP-complete. You can view it as finding coefficients from `{-1, 0, 1}` for each number, such that the sum of numbers multiplied by their coefficients is equal to Z.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately your question doesn't seem like the type to be answered here; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Have you made any attempts to write code for this? Also, you haven't specified which programming language you are using unless I missed it somewhere.


Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service,  but we are happy to help you troubleshoot any issues you might have when developing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of subset sum which can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time using dynamic programming

Here`s O(n*W) solution: where w is sum of abs(a[i])

1. lets say `dp[i][j] = 1` if we can get sum of j after considering i items and 0 otherwise
2. base case: `dp[0][0] = 1`
3. other case, when considering element i, lets say its value is a[i]:

   - we can reach some state dp[i][j] from sates:

     - `dp[i-1][j]` (skip current element)
     - `dp[i-1][j-a]` (usecurrent element with + sign)
     - `dp[i-1][j+a]` (usecurrent element with - sign)

So solution looks like this:

```
dp[0][0]=1

for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
for(int j=-W; j<=W; j++)
dp[i][j]|=dp[i-1][j] | dp[i-1][j-a[i]] | dp[i-1][j+a[i]]

return dp[n][Z]
```